# iOS: Embedded tableview doesn't "scroll up" when entering a value into textfield

Tags: ios, tableview

I have an embedded tableview within a view. The top rows of this embedded table view are always visible, even with the keyboard. If you enter something into the lower cells I want them to scroll up (as usual) in order to see what you're entering into the textfields. However this doesn't happen and they remain hidden behind the keyboard. How can I change this?

Thx
Michael

Comment: You have to manually scroll the table when user types.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706129/how-to-scroll-view-up-when-keyboard-appears) out

Answer (score 0):

You don't get that behavior for free, you need to scroll the content up/down yourself. A `UITableView` inherits from a `UIScrollView`, so scrolling is not the actual problem. To scroll, you can set its `contentSize` and `contentOffset` (even animated if you like).

The first thing is, you want to listen to these notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

These will tell you whether the keyboard will show or hide. In each of these methods, change the `contentOffset` and `contentSize` of your `UITableView` accordingly:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // keyboard info
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    UIViewAnimationOptions animationCurve = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    // offsets
    UIView *cell = myTextField.superView; // assuming your text field is a direct child of the UITableViewCell
    CGFloat textFieldBottomY = self.view.frame.origin.y + myTableView.frame.origin.y - myTableView.contentOffset.y + cell.frame.origin.y + myTextField.origin.y + myTextField.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat keyboardTopY = keyboardRect.origin.y;

    // new content size: add size to be able to scroll
    originalContentOffset = myTableView.contentOffset; // store the original content offset to set back when keyboard hides
    originalContentSize = myTableView.contentSize; // store the original content size to set back when keyboard hides
    CGSize newContentSize = myTableView.contentSize;
    newContentSize.height += keyboardRect.size.height;
    myTableView.contentSize = newContentSize;

    // scroll to just beneath your text field
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0 options:animationCurve animations:^{
        myTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, textFieldBottomY - keyboardTopY);
    } completion:NULL];
}
```

To reset everything:

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // keyboard info
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    UIViewAnimationOptions animationCurve = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    // move content
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0 options:animationCurve animations:^{
        myTableView.contentOffset = originalContentOffset;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            // reset content size
            myTableView.contentSize = originalContentSize;
        }
    }];
}
```

To detect which text field is selected/active:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    myTextField = textField;
}
```

I didn't test out the code on a `UITableView`, but I used it very recently on a `UIScrollView`. Again - since a `UITableView` inherits from a `UIScrollVIew`, this should not be a problem. If the table view does not scroll correctly to just beneath the text field, the value of `textFieldBottomY` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-keeping-content-from-underneath-the-keyboard/) with a detailed explanation to achieve this. It explains the method on `UIScrollView`, which will also work on `UITableView`.

If you had used a `UITableViewController` instead of manually adding `UITableView` on a view, you would had got the behavior automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to scroll to the position between the TextField and Tableview, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265559/get-uitableview-to-scroll-to-the-selected-uitextfield-and-avoid-being-hidden-by).