# How to make scroll up in list view when keyboard is appear

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scroll

I would like to know that is there any way to do in android like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8706129/1156041). I used `ListView` and add the `EditText` in it. I got same problem as above question. I cann't find the answer in android.

Thanks.

Comment: "I cann't find the answer in android." Third link found with the search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599451/how-to-make-an-android-view-scrollable-when-the-keyboard-appears

Comment: thank for ur link. I have footer bar in my view. When I change as ur link, , the footer bar is above the keyboard. I would like to hide the footer bar when keyboard appear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your manifest, try this

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

</activity>
```

What you need is **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"**

Try!

Comment: I have an actionBar and this method scrolls it somewhere up off screen.

Comment: I have editText inside listview, and the behaviour is strange, when scrolled, the text in editText is gone..

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with the keyboard overlapping the listview, but **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** didn't work for me.

However, **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** did.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Answer (score 1):

smoothScrollToPosition method of LilstView class

Answer (score 1):

If it's a kind of sms list view, this could be achieved by adding in the manifest this line:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

and adding a touch listener to edit view:

```
myEditView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                myView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        myListView.setSelection(myAdapter.getCount());
                    }
                }, 500);        

            return false;
        }
    });
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{

    myEditView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myListView.setSelection(myAdapter.getCount());
                }
            }, 500);    
    super.onResume();
}
```